# Javascript/Jquery parse excel into text

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I am fairly new to javascript but I would like to possibly create a javascript of jquery that would go through all
the records in the excel sheet row by row, and for each record parse in TEXT file the cell information in one and the same

html-style
structure, like the one one below.

```
| Cell1| IMG path | IMGthumbpath | Cell4| Cell5| Cell6 | Cell7 |

xxx       xxx          xxx         xxx     xxx  xxx    xxx. 
...       ...          ...         ...     ...  ...    ...
```

Structure of Text file for each record in xls:

```
<!-- Start of mark up  image. -->

<a href="../<content of IMG path cell>.jpg" class="Gallery" onClick="return xxx">

<[img] src="../<content of IMGthumbpath cell>.jpg" alt="<content of Cell1>" title="<content of Cell1>"/>

<span><content of Cell1> </span>

</a>

<div class="Gallery">
<h3><Content of Cell1></h3> <br />
<b>Desc1: <content of Cell4> <br /> 
<b>Desc2:&nbsp;</b> <content of Cell5> <br /> 
<b>Desc3:&nbsp;</b> <Content of Cell6> <br />
<b>Desc4:&nbsp;</b> <Content of Cell7> <br />
</div>

<!--End of mark up  image. -->
```

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: As far as I know jQuery nor javascript can work on csv files, you will need to use the csv to create a html table (very easy) and then use the jQuery to interact with the table

Comment: to parse Excel, you need an ActiveXobject, only supported in IE, and since you are new to javascript, i dont recommend getting started with a this complexe task

Comment: It depends on where is the source of CSV data. On client side or on server side? Here is something about parsing CSV using JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data